# In Jeremiah 25:11 are the seventy years literal?

Tags: jeremiah

Jeremiah 25:11 KJV

> And this whole land shall be a desolation, and an astonishment; and these nations shall serve the king of Babylon seventy years.

Were the seventy years of serving Babylon a duration of time or were they literal calendar 12-13 month years (the Jewish leap year having 13 months)? Were leap years considered in those seventy years?

To explain this question a bit more, a year would not always be seen as a duration of time, such as hours and minutes, but rather a revolution of time, meaning everything repeats - like the seasons, the harvest etc. So if those seventy years prophesied in Jeremiah weren't seen as a duration of time, then leap years or seasons would have to be considered and if that's the case, why would God make such an fuzzy timeline for the Jews in Babylon? It would've been difficult to determine when the seventy years began and when they would end.

Comment: We *know* when the Babylonian exile ended: when Cyrus conquered Babylon in 538 BC. If we start with the second siege (and the fall) of Jerusalem by Nebuchadnezzar, 587 BC, the exile was 49 years. If we start with the first siege of Jerusalem, 597 BC, that's 59 years. Even if we start with Daniel 1's mistaken chronology which places the first siege in 605 BC, that's 67 years. No matter how we slice it, the exile to Babylon was less than 70 years. This seems to limit any valid interpretations to the 70 years being a rounded number, a symbolic number, or an errant literal number.

Comment: But the Jews possibly returned in 537 BC, making the exile 68 years if you count it from 605 BC. The thing is that is 68 solar years but 70 lunar years. I know the Jews possibly used leap years into their soli lunar calendar system, but because the leap years were empirical and somewhat unpredictable, there had to be some kind of general time duration of a 'year' so people could plan things in the future, or, in Jeremiah's situation, make a prophecy.

Comment: Relying on ifs and maybes to arrive at a predetermined conclusion seems more in the realm of apologetics. If that's what the intention behind your question is, it may be better suited for [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)? Otherwise, I think your question may be bordering on 'too broad' for the scope of Hermeneutics.SE.

Comment: I thought hermeneutics was about interpretation? Can't the seventy years be interpreted? Just like the seventy weeks of Daniel being interpreted?

Comment: Neither the Jews nor the Babylonians used (non-intercalated) lunar years. The only people who ever did so were and are the Muslims. "Lunar years" are irrelevant in this context.

Comment: I'm not saying their civil calendar was strictly lunar like Islam, but it definitely was lunar based, with the majority of their years being 12 lunar months. The fact that a leap year was only declared at the end of twelve months after the announcement of the high priest or Sanhedrin means that a leap year was practically unpredictable. So there had to be some kind of general time measurement for a "year" for people to plan things on, such as a contract, to make ot more precise. The Jews were in a foreign land with a different calendar to live by

Comment: @fdb do you suggest that the muslims ( 7th AD) were the first to use (inventores) of lunar calendar?

Comment: @A.Meshu: No, he's simply saying that the Muslims were the first to use a strictly twelve-month lunar calendar, without any intercalation whatsoever (so as to distinguish themselves from Judaism).

Answer (score 1):

> In [Jeremiah 25:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah_25:11&version=KJV&interface=print), are the [seventy years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_captivity) literal ?

Apparently so:

- <sup>2 Kings 25:8-9</sup> And in the fifth month, on the seventh day of the month, which is the **nineteenth year** of king **[Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebuchadnezzar_II)**, came Nebuzaradan, captain of the guard, a servant of the king of Babylon, unto Jerusalem: and **he burnt [the house of the Lord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon%27s_Temple)**, and the king's house, and all the houses of Jerusalem, and every great man's house burnt he with fire.
- <sup>Ezra 6:15</sup> And **[this house](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple) was finished** on the third day of the month Adar, which was in the **sixth year** of the reign of **[Darius the king](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_the_Great)**.

There are about **seven decades** between the [destruction of the first temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(587_BC))<sup>(587/6 BC)</sup> and the completion of the construction of the second.<sup>(516/5 BC)</sup>

---

Alternately, from the battles of Megiddo<sup>(609 BC)</sup> and Carchemish,<sup>(605 BC)</sup> marking the **first** incursions or intrusions of the newly-established [Babylonian empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Babylonian_Empire) into (the vicinity of) Israeli territories, and until Cyrus' decree to rebuild the temple,<sup>(539/8 BC)</sup> there are also **seven decades**:

- <sup>2 Kings 23:29</sup> In his days [Pharaoh Nechoh king of Egypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necho_II) went up against the king of Assyria to the river Euphrates: and **[king Josiah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah)** went against him; and he slew him at **[Megiddo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Megiddo_(609_BC))**, when he had seen him.
- <sup>Jeremiah 46:1-2</sup> The word of the Lord which came to [Jeremiah the prophet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah) against the Gentiles; against Egypt, against the army of [Pharaoh Necho king of Egypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necho_II), which was by the river Euphrates in **[Carchemish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Carchemish)**, which [Nebuchadrezzar king of Babylon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebuchadnezzar_II) smote in the **fourth year** of **[Jehoiakim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehoiakim)** the son of [Josiah king of Judah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah).
- <sup>2 Chronicles 36:22-23; Ezra 1:1-2</sup> Now in the **first year** of **[Cyrus king of Persia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_the_Great)**, that the word of the Lord spoken by the mouth of Jeremiah might be accomplished, the Lord stirred up the spirit of Cyrus king of Persia, that he made a proclamation throughout all his kingdom, and put it also in writing, saying, Thus saith Cyrus king of Persia, All the kingdoms of the earth hath **the Lord God of heaven** given me; and he hath charged me to **build him [an house in Jerusalem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_in_Jerusalem), which is in Judah**.

Comment: The second temple did not begin to be built until the seventy years of captivity had ended.  It was completed within the seventy years _following_ the captivity, but the temple had lain in ruins well over half a century before it began to be rebuilt, and took 46 years to rebuild after that.

Comment: @Polyhat: You seem to have confused the timespan before the edict of Cyrus, with the one following it. It was 23, not 46 years, from the first year of Cyrus II (539/8 BC) until the sixth year of Darius I (516/5 BC), as already explained above. And it lay in ruins for about 47 years years, from the siege of Jerusalem (587/6 BC) until the first year of Cyrus II (539/8 BC), as also described above.

Comment: The Temple was destroyed after Daniel had been in Babylon ~18 years.  This time is ascertainable via the prophecy of Ezekiel 4 in which the 390 years culminate at the destruction of the temple, which coincides with the dethronement of the last king of Judah. This would mean your figures for this part are about five years short (47 --> 52). But the bigger difference is when you try to reduce the 46 to 23! "Then said the Jews, Forty and six years was this temple in building, and wilt thou rear it up in three days?" (John 2:20)  I don't expect you will think to know the time better than they did.

Comment: @Polyhat: Thank you for detailing your reasoning process, so that I may actually understand where you're coming from, and, as such, be able to write a meaningfully relevant reply. For starters, the years in question can be found in the linked encyclopedic articles, in the rectangle to the right; they are certainly not my own private and personal invention. Secondly, John's 46 years relate to the fact that [Herod the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_the_Great#Architectural_achievements) began some serious construction work in the area around 20/19 BC, in his 18th year of reign.

Comment: I find most commentaries to be sadly inaccurate with respect to Bible chronologies.  It takes some real study to get to the facts, and most have only a partial understanding, therefore, cannot accurately do the reckoning.  For some strange reason, Bible chronology has fascinated me since I was a child, and I continue to learn. I have often found that others' reckoning of the times was partially guesswork on their part as they struggled to fill in the gaps. There are always gaps; always challenges with chronology--that's what makes it fun. In any case, I'll use the Bible over the encyclopedias.

Comment: @Polyhat: The real question is not whether to use the bible, but how.

Answer (score 1):

2 Kings 24:1-2 (NIV) read

> 1 During Jehoiakim’s reign, Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon invaded the land, and Jehoiakim became his vassal for three years. But then he turned against Nebuchadnezzar and rebelled.
>
> 2 The Lord sent Babylonian, Aramean, Moabite and Ammonite raiders against him to destroy Judah, in accordance with the word of the Lord proclaimed by his servants the prophets.

Nebuchadnezzar attacked Jerusalem in 605BC, by that time Judah was his vassal for three years. Therefore Judah began to serve the Babylonian king since 608BC, until Persia conquered Babylon in 539BC, lasted for 70 years.

**Jeremiah prophesy was true to its literal meaning.**

Answer (score 0):

**Background**
Stanley Leathes notes there is a question about measuring the 70-year period:

> It is at least curious and interesting to observe that from 606 B.C., the approximate date of the delivery of Jeremiah's prophecy, to 536 B.C., the approximate date of the edict of Cyrus, the first termination of the captivity, was a period of seventy years.
>
> Again, from 598 B.C., the approximate date of Jehoiachin's captivity (2 Kings xxiv. 12), to 528 B.C., the approximate date of the close of the first period of amnesty and of the counter efforts against the decree of Cyrus (Ezra iv. 6), which were virtually a renewal of the captivity, was a period of seventy years. Thus the captivity was eight years in progress, as was also the return. Also from 588 B.C., the approximate date of the completion of the captivity by the destruction of the city and temple (2 Kings xxv. 8), to 518 B.C., the approximate date of the decree of Darius (Ezra v1. 1), which was a second termination of the captivity, was a period of seventy years. Also from 527 B.C., the approximate date of the second renewal of the captivity (Ezra iv. 6), to the decree of Artaxerxes in 457 B.C., which was the close of the captivity, was a period of seventy years.
>
> It is undoubtedly hard to prove or disprove the exactitude of these several periods within a year or so, but for those who insist that the seventy years are a round number it is plainly needless to do so; while, at all events, the reoccurrence of the number seventy in connection with the history of the captivity and the return of the Jews is, to say the least, striking.
>
> We have contemporary evidence from Zech. i. 12 that the Jews of that age were themselves in doubt as to when the seventy years ended; because they did not clearly know from when to date their commencement. It is reserved for us, in looking back over all the history, to see that the very uncertainty attaching to the determination of the seventy years is itself a confirmation of the reality and genuineness of the prophecy concerning them, inasmuch as not in one way only but in several it may be shown to have fulfilled itself...<sup>1</sup>

He recognizes the issue was knowing when the 70-year period begin. However as Leathes shows, regardless of which date is used, it was fulfilled. This is affirmed by Daniel who recognized both the number of years and a point of fulfillment:

> In the first year of Darius the son of Ahasuerus, by descent a Mede, who was made king over the realm of the Chaldeans— in the first year of his reign, I, Daniel, perceived in the books the number of years that, according to the word of the LORD to Jeremiah the prophet, must pass before the end of the desolations of Jerusalem, namely, seventy years. (Daniel 9:1-2) [ESV]

There is good reason to believe the people were able to accurately count the years.

Two methods, one using the natural world, the other using the calendar of the LORD could be used to measure the period of a year.

**Natural Means**
There is created method for measuring a year:

> And God said, “Let there be lights in the expanse of the heavens to separate the day from the night. And let them be for signs and for seasons, and for days and years, and let them be lights in the expanse of the heavens to give light upon the earth.” And it was so. (Genesis 1:14-15)

Celestial objects were created to be signs for years.<sup>2</sup> There are four easily identified candidates which mark the period of one year: the summer or winter [solstice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solstice), or the summer or winter [equinox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox). Therefore, regardless of any human calendar in use in Babylon (or Jerusalem) which might misstate the length of a year, God created a precise method of identifying the completion of a year.

In addition, the Babylonians celebrated the summer solstice with festivals to the god [Tammuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammuz_(Babylonian_calendar)) so even "non astronomers" in Babylon would know one year had passed.

**Feasts of the LORD**
The most frequent event on the LORD's calendar is the weekly Sabbath. Since 52 Sabbaths totals 364 days, one year can be measured with reasonable accuracy. As the prophecy is given in years, it would not be necessary to precisely measure the exact number of days, but the weekly Sabbaths could be used to "get closer" to the precise number of days in the entire 70-year period by counting an additional Sabbath every seventh year (corresponding to the Sabbath year in Leviticus 25).

The years could also be counted using any one of the seven annual events:<sup>3</sup>
[image]
However, these annual events are observed using the monthly calendar which seemingly creates potential uncertainty or a "fuzzy timeline" which is at the heart of the OP's question:

> ...since the lunar year was about 11 days less than the solar year, it was periodically necessary to intercalate a thirteenth month in order that new year's day should not fall before the spring of the year (March-April). No precise details are known of the method used by the Hebrews to accommodate the agricultural with the lunar calendar.<sup>4</sup>

On the surface there is an arbitrary nature to using the monthly calendar to observe annual events. Yet it is important to remember, there is no celestial object created for the purpose of measuring a month. Nor is there any proscribed way to correlate some number of months to a year. The alignment of the first month of the year to the solar cycle was done by correlating man's work to the created seasons:

> “Speak to the people of Israel and say to them, When you come into the land that I give you and reap its harvest, you shall bring the sheaf of the firstfruits of your harvest to the priest, and he shall wave the sheaf before the LORD, so that you may be accepted. On the day after the Sabbath the priest shall wave it. (Leviticus 23:10-11)

The required offering for the Feast of Fruits was the first of the harvest from that year. Thus the monthly calendar was not adjusted at random; it was done to align the first month with the first harvest which was the first season of the year. Using Leathes' terminology, one may debate the exactitude of the specific day on which the year begins and ends, but there is no confusion over the reality a new harvest means a new year.

Moreover, the human activities on Feast of First Fruits effectively function as annual memorials to God's work, the solar cycle, man's annual work and weekly rest:

- It follows the Passover which is marked by offering a year-old lamb and so recognizes the previous year of God's work in providing the lamb and man's care in keeping it.
- It follows the first harvest and so recognizes a new solar cycle.
- It follows the last day of man's work (before the rest of the Sabbath) and recognizes the last day of man's weekly rest.

In other words, the Feast of First Fruits not only marks the period of a year, it does so at a time of year and in a way which connects the new year to the previous year and is grounded both in two aspects of nature (the solar and reproductive cycles) and man's annual work and weekly rest.

**Conclusion**
There are two valid ways a person can measure a one year period and the only requirement to know the fulfillment is to count seventy 1-year periods. There is a valid question over when one should start to count, but regardless of the starting point, there is a fulfillment 70-years later.

It is impossible to know with certainty which method was used, but the logical candidate would be the Passover and the days of Unleavened Bread which immediately follow which include a weekly Sabbath and the Feast of First Fruits. The Passover is a retrospective look remembering the LORD's work in bringing the Israelites out of bondage in Egypt and would serve prospectively in faith the LORD would end the captivity and bring the Israelites out of Babylon.

Finally, there is another interesting aspect to the connection between the LORD's calendar, the nature solar cycle, and a 70-year period. When 70 years are counted using only the weekly Sabbaths adding a Sabbath every seventh year, the total number of days at the end of 70-years is 25,550, which is 17.5 days short of 70-years calculated using a 365.25 day solar cycle. Thus, in the 70<sup>th</sup> year, the fulfillment using the solar method would place the end of the captivity immediately after the 17<sup>th</sup> of the month, which in the first month is one week after the Passover Lamb was chosen and in the seventh month is one week after the Day of Atonement.

Like the different ways to mark the beginning of the 70-years each has a corresponding fulfillment, the natural method of counting has a point of fulfillment marked by a confluence of the weekly 7-day cycle and annual calendar of the LORD.

---

Notes:
1. Stanley Leathes, [*Old Testament Prophecy: Its Witness as a Record of Divine Foreknowledge*](https://archive.org/stream/oldtestamentprop00leat#page/178/mode/2up), Hodder and Stoughton, 1880, pp. 178-179
2. There is no mention of months or objects created to determine the length of a month in the creation account.
3. *The New Bible Dictionary*, WM. B. Eerdmans Publishing, 1962, p. 177
4. Ibid., p. 178

Comment: Well researched. Once again, there's a traditional down-vote without any reasons, so I assume it must have been to ensure your humility. I offset it with my up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we ought to consider the possible symbolism of the number "seventy".

The Biblical association of the number 7 with the Creator God is well-known. I find it helpful in dealing with prophetic numbers to regard 10 as the number of completeness, or "the whole world", as in the case of the "10 kings" of Revelation ch17. In that case, "70" is "7x10", which could indicate "God's completeness" or "God's work for the world". In support of this theory we can find other instances of the use of "70". There is the fact that 70 elders (not 12) accompanied Moses to see a vision of God (Exodus ch24 v9). The mission of 70 disciples in Luke ch10. The traditional number of the translators of the Septuagint.

I propose that "70 years" means "the complete time of exile that God has appointed". In which case, literal accuracy ceases to be important.